# How should a question be formulated to call for an ablative of respect as the answer?

Tags: interrogative

Imagine a sentence that contains an ablative of respect: Quintus est pedibus aeger.

Now that same sentence with the ablative of respect removed: Quintus est aeger.

What is the best way to formulate a question to which the missing ablative of respect would be supplied as the answer?

Some possibilities :

Quintus est aeger.
Quo?
Pedibus.

Quintus est aeger.
In quo?
Pedibus.

Quintus est aeger.
Quomodo?
Pedibus.

I'm not confident in any of my answers.

EDIT: I'm looking for a generalizable formula, if there is one, for asking for a bare ablative. By contrast, when an adverbial is expressed through a prepositional phrase, one can reliably formulate a question by making the object of the preposition an interrogative. Is there a similar formula for adverbials expressed by a bare ablative?

Comment: Intuitively I would say "Qua parte corporis?" Simply "Quo?" seems a pretty general question, especially since *aeger* also can have an abl. causae (*aeger morbo, vulnere, etc.*).

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel That's a great approach! Can you write that in an answer? I have an upvote waiting with your name on it. A question that can only be interpreted to contain an ablative of respect is the best bet I can imagine.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel I agree that "qua parte corporis?" would work for this exact question with this precise lexical content. But it doesn't generalize. Is there no generalizable formulation to ask for an ablative of respect? To put my question in perspective, if an adverbial is expressed through a prepositional phrase, converting a statement to a question is simple. The interrogative becomes the object of the preposition. But what about the case of a bare ablative?